# Getting associated model attributes using strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building a custom method and i want to access attributes by using strings.

for example

```
@search["attribute_name"]
```

While this works, when i try to get associated attribute values its not working.

example: `@search["category_id"]["name"]`

can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: please explain bit more to help you out

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'send' method to access object attribute on rum time.

Example:- @search.send('name')

Comment: Hello thanka for reply but i want to do it for association attribute